# Citrus: Need to validate the status code while receiving. What is the element name?

Tags: citrus-framework, citrus-engine

1. Need to validate the status code while JMS receiving. What is the element name?
2. Is it possible to get the error code in the citrus HTML report?
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mtVQ.png)

```html
<send endpoint="jms:${INLET}?connectionFactory=${AMQConnection}" >
            <message name="helloMessage" type="text">
                <resource file="file:D:/INPUT/${INPUT}"/>
            </message>
            <header>
                <element name="scenarioId" value="${IntegrationID}" />
                <element name="messageID" value="156666"/>
            </header>
        </send>
<receive endpoint="jms:${OUTLET}?connectionFactory=${OutletConnectionFactory}">
    <message name="helloMessage">       
    <resource file="file:D:/expectedOutput/${OUTPUT}"/> 
    </message>
    <header>
        <element name="scenarioId" value="${IntegrationID}"/>
        <element name="messageID" value="156666"/>
         NEED TO VALIDATE STATUS CODE FOR JMS AND SHOW IN REPORT
    </header>
</receive>
```

Comment: @christophd Please help with this.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the JMS status code? There is no such thing in JMS. Am I getting something wrong here?

Comment: Yes for JMS Queues such as message received or not status code something